# Dual of idempotent semirings

Tags: ct.category-theory, semirings

By an idempotent semiring I mean a set equipped with a join-semilattice with bottom structure $(0,+)$ and a multiplicative monoid $(1,\cdot)$ such that the following equations hold:

$a \cdot (b + c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c$
$\;\;\;\; (a + b) \cdot c = a \cdot c + b \cdot c$
$\;\;\;\; a \cdot 0 = 0 = 0 \cdot a$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category whose objects are the idempotent semirings and whose morphisms are the algebra morphisms i.e. functions preserving the operations. Is there any known concrete characterisation of $\mathcal{A}^{op}$? What about in the case where one restricts to the full subcategory of finitely generated algebras?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in the literature on quantales? A quantale is the same as an idempotent semiring, except that quantales are required to have all (not just finite) joins, and correspondingly multiplication has to distribute over all joins.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can ask for a characterisation of $\mathcal{A}^{op}$ that is any more concrete than the definition.

However, $\mathcal{A}^{op}$ can be described in alternative terms via scheme theory.  This won't describe it in any simpler terms, and in fact it introduces a good deal of extra complication, but it can perhaps be useful sometimes because it puts things in a more geometric setting. In standard algebraic geometry the category of commutative rings is equivalent to the opposite of the category of affine schemes (over spec $\mathbb{Z}$).   Similarly, your category of idempotent commutative semirings is equivalent to the opposite of the category of affine schemes over spec $S$, where $S$ is the initial object in idempotent semirings ($S=${0,1}).
This embeds as a full subcategory of the category of affine schemes over $\mathbb{N}$ (the semiring of natural numbers).  For references on the scheme theory of semirings, see:

1. arXiv:math/0509684, Toen-Vaquie, Under Spec Z
2. arXiv:0704.2030, Durov, New Approach to Arakelov Geometry
3. arXiv:1103.1745, Lorscheid, The geometry of blueprints. Part I: Algebraic background and scheme theory